# "TypeError: expect(...).to.have.been.calledWith is not a function" With Karma

Tags: sinon, chai, karma-mocha

I have the following Karma Conf...

```
var webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
webpackConfig.entry = {};
webpackConfig.plugins = [];
var globFlat = require('glob-flat');

// TODO: These are redundant with the webpack plugin...
var appFiles = globFlat.sync([
  './src/main/coffee/**/*.coffee'
]);
var styleFiles = globFlat.sync([
]);
var dependencyFiles = [
  'test-main.js',
  './src/main/typescripts/**/*.ts',
  'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'
];
var testFiles = globFlat.sync([
  './test/main/webapp/**/*.coffee',
  './test/main/webapp/**/*.js'
]);

var files = dependencyFiles.concat(appFiles, styleFiles, testFiles);
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai-spies', 'chai', 'sinon', 'sinon-chai'],
    files: files,
    exclude: [ ],
    preprocessors: {
      './src/main/coffee/**/*.coffee': ['webpack'],
      './src/main/typescripts/**/*.ts': ['webpack'],
      './test/**/*.coffee': ['coffee']
    },
    webpack: webpackConfig,
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
};
```

But when I run a few of the tests break with...

> TypeError: expect(...).to.have.been.calledWith is not a function

I don't understand because I am including sinon-chai

Comment: can we see some test code ?

Comment: Actually the code I provided was enough I will provide answer in a second.

Answer (score 3):

There were a couple problems here...

1. Order
   My current order was `['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai-spies', 'chai', 'sinon', 'sinon-chai']`. This is **read right to left** not left to right. So I needed to change to `['mocha', 'requirejs', 'chai-spies', 'sinon-chai', 'chai', 'sinon']`. This way sinon-chai is loaded after sinon and chai.
2. RequireJS doesn't work with 'sinon-chai' https://github.com/kmees/karma-sinon-chai/issues/11

My final ended up being...

`['mocha', 'sinon-chai', 'chai', 'sinon']`